# Function to convert a wordpress querystring into a permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

is it possible to have a php-function, which converts a wordpress querystring, e.g. year=2017&monthnum=03 into it's permalink, depending on the current settings, e.g. /2017/03/ ?

I thought i could find the answer in the WP_Rewrite class, but i couldn't.

Comment: Have you checked permalink setting properly?

Comment: @AnkitaTanti What you mean? It has nothing to do with the permalink settings. What i want is a function, which i hand over a plain query string and its then return the permalink to that query string.

For example, you can call the site: www.myhost.com/?year=2017&monthnum=03 and you will be redirected to www.myhost.com/2017/03/.

I just want to know if such a function is possible and how.

Answer (score 0):

1. [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) — Parses the string into variables
2. [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) — Join array elements with a string
3. [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) — Return all the values of an array

[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/mvNBCV)

```
function convert($string){

$str = $string;

parse_str($str, $array);

$value = implode("/", array_values($array));

return '/'. $value .'/';
}

echo convert('year=2017&monthnum=03');
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what i'm looking for. If the querystring in this example starts with the monthnum arg, the resulting permalink will not be functional. Instead it would lead to a 404 error. I'm looking for a method to mimic the way wordpress handle this, but with the possibility to use the converted permalink in my script.

Comment: Yes, if result starts wuth the monthnum arg you can use **if** PHP condition.